# How to create a nested tensorflow structure?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, keras

I have trouble with creating nested pattern using Tensorflow backend. What I want to achieve is to use two model inside of one session. I trained a model and want to use it inside of the SSD COCO object detection model. By the way I assign the model outside of the graph and session(in order to load model once). Whenever I try to run my codes, return an error like:

> ValueError: Tensor Tensor("activation_76/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 4),
>   dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

I search other Stack Overflow pages however I could not solve my issue.
Can someone help me to understand the problem and solution ?

Later on I search on the net and found this site :

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462

and then I tried the line of "model._make_predict_function()" but it did not work for me and this time it returned that one:

> ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", dtype=float32) must be from the
>   same graph as Tensor("total:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN-3")

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:


      ret, image_np = cap.read()

      if W is None or H is None:
          (H, W)= image_np.shape[:2]


      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')

      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = \
              detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')



      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

      boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
      scores = np.squeeze(scores)
      classes = np.squeeze(classes)

      indices = np.argwhere(classes == 1)
      boxes = np.squeeze(boxes[indices])

      scores = np.squeeze(scores[indices])
      classes = np.squeeze(classes[indices])

      rects = []
      boxes = scale(boxes, 0, 1)

      my_prediction = model.predict("Some images")

      """ ^ these codes return an error """
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `model = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN-3")` within the `with detection_graph.as_default():` context?

Comment: I tried as you said it did not work for me. I tried to put after with `tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:` and before the While loop it worked for me. I really appreaciate for your answer @frankegoesdown because I was trying to solve this issue almost one day.